# Difference between quiet, enhanced and active networks

Tags: the-sun

For my research about the sun activity I need to process pictures of the sun. I want the pictures to show 3 stages the quiet, enhanced and active network. I couldn't find any information in the internet about how these 3 networks actually look and how they differ from each other. Can somebody explain this to me? What is showing on which picture?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "network" in this context, but on the [SOHO website](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/data/synoptic/sunspots_earth/), you can find pictures of the Sun for every day since 2006.

Quiet: there aren't any visible structures at the surface of the Sun
[image]

Active: the black spots are sunspots
[image: Active Sun in 2014]

Comment: The "network" refers to the bright cells seen in chromospheric lines like Ca-K, separated by the darker "internetwork". "Quiet", "enhanced", and "active" refer to the strength of the magnetic field, I think.